# Package amsaddr.sty

Tags: amsmath, packages, miktex2.9, directory

How to enable package `amsaddr` for MiKTeX. There is not `amsaddr` in directory of TeX. That's why TeX cannot find `amsaddr.sty`.

Running the file `amsaddr.dtx` I have this picture, but there is not file `amsaddr.sty`:

[image: compiled dtx file]

Edit: I am using an MiKTeX admin installation ...

Comment: `amsaddr` is an add-on package; it's not part of the AMS package support.  But it's on CTAN, so miktex should be able to add it "on the fly".

Comment: So, I've downloaded zip file of amsaddr from CTAN, and what should I do next?

Comment: Unzip the zip file, then run `amsaddr.ins` through latex.  (This is the instruction in the README file.)

Comment: yes, but texmaker doesn't see this file and nothing see it.

Comment: I'm not a miktex user, so I don't know the best answer for this.  How to add a package to the miktex "library" should be described in the miktex documentation.

Comment: Well, I'm a MiKTEX user and I can see package `amsaddr` in the MiKTeX console, in register `packages`.  Did you install basic miktex or complete (netinstaller) MiKTeX? You should use MiKTeX Console to install package `amsaddr` ... Do you have an admin or user installation of MiKTeX?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Please consider upvoting/accepting it then. That is the way here to say "Thank you for your help!"

Answer (score 2):

Well, with an complete installation of MiKTeX (admin mode) I can see the package `amsaddr` in the MiKTeX Console:

[image: miktex console packages]

As you can see I added name `amsaddr` (see red arrow in image) and selected to search for it (red circle marked with 1) to get a list of installed packages `amsaddr` by MiKTeX.

If you have not already installed that package the + sign in the red circle marked with 2 will be dark and shows you can install this package by clicking on the + sign!

BTW: To get the window I showed you you have to start the MiKTeX Console in the apps of windows, then click on `use in admin mode` (because you also have an admin installation) and the click on `Packages` I marked in the image with the long red arrow ...

If you did changes in user mode it is possible you have to do that again in user mode ...

Because you gave us no [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I can not test if I get the same error message you got ...